# Any way to analyze locks after the fact?

Tags: postgresql

Say I had a lock that lasted for a couple of hours and caused a lot of queries to wait for it, but it was released before I had the chance to investigate it. Is there any way to see where that lock was? Anything in particular to look for in the logs?

Comment: Doubtful - You could set up periodic process dumps, though, and analyze those. What OS are you running? Is it a recurring issue?

Comment: I run Ubuntu. No, it's a one-time issue that I want to trace. I was hoping there is some hint about the long locks in the logs. I can see the lock in munin (lots of queries waiting for a lock), but I want to find out what exactly the lock was.

Comment: If it was a database-level lock, you might be in luck - it's common for that info to be logged. I probably won't be able to help, but if you post more information about your database and logging configuration, perhaps someone else can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past and wrote a simple bash script that checked on the database and saved a copy of the views I wanted with a timestamp on it every minute so I could later look at the data when the problem had passed.  Here's the one I used, it grabs pg_stat_activity when there are more than 50 backends connected.  Feel free to mangle it in whatever way works for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
threshold=50;
dt=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`;
active=`/usr/bin/psql www -Atc "select count(*) from pg_stat_activity where current_query not ilike '%idle%';"`
if [[ active -gt threshold ]]; then
    echo "there are "$active" backends";
    echo "creating backup for pg_stat as pg_stat_bk_$dt"
    psql www -c "select * into monitoring.pg_stat_bk_$dt from pg_stat_activity where current_query not ilike '%idle%';"
fi
```

Comment: You can throw in a query from this page: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring to get a nice view of what's blocking what.